# Convert string in HH:MM:SS format to seconds in Google BigQuery (Standard SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a custom dimension called "video length" in my tables from Google Analytics. The data are string values, but some take on 3 of the following formats:

1) HH:MM:SS (for example, 1:54:55)

2) MM:SS (for example, 2:26)

3) # of seconds (for example, for a video with 2:26 length, the length would be **146**)

- I've attempted a case statement to zero in on the cases where the value was of either HH:MM:SS format or MM:SS format as well as the character length.
- I've also added additional zeros to values that follow MM:SS format.
- I had to `CAST`in order to `INT64` so that I can add up the values to get the string.

The query is valid, however when I run the query, I get an error that reads "Failed to parse input string"

```
select old_video_length,
 case 
  when videoLength like "%:%" and length(videoLength) > 7 then cast(cast(parse_time("%E*S",videoLength) as string) as int64)+cast(cast(parse_time("%M",videoLength) as string) as int64)*60+cast(cast(parse_time("%H",videoLength) as string) as int64)*3600
  when videoLength like "%:%" and length(videoLength) between 6 and 7 then cast(cast(parse_time("%E*S",concat("0",videoLength)) as string) as int64)+cast(cast(parse_time("%M",concat("0",videoLength)) as string) as int64)*60+cast(cast(parse_time("%H",concat("0",videoLength)) as string) as int64)*3600
  when videoLength like "%:%" and length(videoLength) <= 5 then cast(cast(parse_time("%E*S",concat("00:",videoLength)) as string) as int64)+cast(cast(parse_time("%M",concat("00:",videoLength)) as string) as int64)*60+cast(cast(parse_time("%H",concat("00:",videoLength)) as string) as int64)*3600
  else cast(videoLength as int64) end as video_length_converted
  from vid_length_table


Ideally, I'd like the table to look like this: 

old_video_length | video_length_converted
1:54:55            6895
2:26               146
146                146
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT videoLength AS old_video_length,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(videoLength, r':\d\d:\d\d$') THEN TIME_DIFF(SAFE.PARSE_TIME('%T', videoLength), TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(videoLength, r':\d\d$') THEN TIME_DIFF(SAFE.PARSE_TIME('%M:%S', videoLength), TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)
    ELSE SAFE_CAST(videoLength AS INT64)
  END AS video_length_converted
FROM `project.dataset.vid_length_table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.vid_length_table` AS (
  SELECT '1:54:55' videoLength UNION ALL
  SELECT '2:26' UNION ALL
  SELECT '146'
)
SELECT videoLength AS old_video_length,
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(videoLength, r':\d\d:\d\d$') THEN TIME_DIFF(SAFE.PARSE_TIME('%T', videoLength), TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(videoLength, r':\d\d$') THEN TIME_DIFF(SAFE.PARSE_TIME('%M:%S', videoLength), TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)
    ELSE SAFE_CAST(videoLength AS INT64)
  END AS video_length_converted
FROM `project.dataset.vid_length_table`
```

with result

```
Row old_video_length    video_length_converted   
1   1:54:55             6895     
2   2:26                146  
3   146                 146
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mikhail! This is super helpful. I tried your approach and it executed successfully. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the string into **timestamp** using the same format as column and we can convert a timestamp into seconds using **UNIX_SECONDS** function

Solution:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
case 
  when videoLength like "%:%:%" then UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%H:%M:%S",videoLength))
  when videoLength like "%:%" then UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%M:%S",videoLength))
  else cast(videoLength as int64) end as video_length_converted
from vid_length_table
```

Example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH vid_length_table as (
  SELECT '1:54:55' videoLength UNION ALL
  SELECT '2:26' UNION ALL
  SELECT '146'
) 
SELECT videoLength AS old_video_length,
case 
  when videoLength like "%:%:%" then UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%H:%M:%S",videoLength))
  when videoLength like "%:%" then UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%M:%S",videoLength))
  else cast(videoLength as int64) end as video_length_converted
from vid_length_table
```

Result:

```
Row old_video_length    video_length_converted   
1   1:54:55             6895     
2   2:26                146  
3   146                 146
```